# Hausdorff and locally compact

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, locally-connected

**Theorem** A space $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff if and only if it is
homeomorphic to an open subset of a compact Hausdorff space.

Can any one give me hint to prove this result. I want the strategy of proof of this particular theorem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $X$ is compact, then you can conclude. If not, use the Alexandroff compactification of $X$.